# How to utilize multiple IP addresses from IP pool given by ISP

Tags: router, switch, nat, subnet

I'm still a student so please forgive me for my ignorance.  I'm still learning.  So I got a T1 line to practice and learn with and they gave me 5 IPs to play with.  For example,8.8.8.0/29  8.8.8.[1-5].  Now I have my line going directly into a Sonicwall Pro 1080 set up with an IP of 8.8.8.1.  I want to add a Cisco 881 and give it the IP address of 8.8.8.2.  I'd like to do it without plugging into the 1080 and use NAT.  So I dropped a switch in front of my 1080 to run the lines in parallel, but once I plugged the 881 in, I lost all Internet access through my 1080.  Is this something that can be done? Is there a better way of doing this?  BTW, the switch I am using is a Buffalo BSL-PS-G2108M.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

On the SonicWall 1080 & the Cisco 881 are you using the same Default-gateway (the IP of the T1)?  In your example, 8.8.8.0/29... 8.8.8.1 would be the default gateway of the T1 provider.  So your sonicwall should be .2, 881 should be .3   (.2-.6 usable IPs)
You are correct that your topology/setup 'SHOULD' Work.  Although you can run into oversubscription issues on your T1 doing that, but is fine for learning/practice.

Answer (score 0):

That should work.  Try plugging a laptop using one of the static IPs into the switch.  I suspect something's up there.

Comment: Can you confirm that 8.8.8.1-8.8.8.5 are usable?  The first or last may be reserved as your gateway address.